# Excel: Conditional Formatting with dates

Tags: excel

I have column G with some of the cells (not all cells) which contain dates. Now I need to use conditional formatting `=($G1-TODAY())<0`
The formula is working correct by highlighting in red the dates which are over-due. The issue that I'm having is that even cells which contain test or which are blank are being highlighted in red.
Is there a ways to only make the formula effective for cells which contain dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional format can test for text in cells or blank cells like this:

```
=AND(NOT(OR(ISTEXT(G1),ISBLANK(G1))),G1<TODAY())
```